# Besides the curl is there any other difference between an electric flux line and a magnetic flux line?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, gauss-law

As far as I know, both types of flux mediating the electromagnetic phenomenon and related forces consist of coherent streams of virtual photons according to the known theory.

Besides the total non-zero curl of a magnetic dipole flux field $\nabla\times B\ne0$ compared to the zero curl of an electric monopole charge, electric flux field $\nabla\times E=0$, which could be also interpreted equal to a hypothetical existing non-zero divergence magnetic dipole flux field $\nabla\cdot B\ne0$ thus a zero total field curl $\nabla\times B=0$.

Is there elementary, ontologically and physically any other known difference between electric and magnetic flux lines of force?

Comment: I don't know about ontology but this may give a different perspective: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160993/why-does-a-magnetic-field-go-anticlockwise-of-the-direction-of-current/161036#161036 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/410714/why-does-a-magnetic-field-curl-around-a-current-carrying-element/410735#410735

Comment: A single electric charge (monopole) will always have zero curl flux lines. A single magnetic dipole charge will always have a total non-zero curl flux lines. So the difference in curl is caused by the nature of the source really, monopole electron charge -e ==> electric flux and dipole magnetic moment of electron (magnetic dipole charge) ==> magnetic flux.
Otherwise IMO, the two flux types are the same phenomenon and mediate the same electromagnetic unified force.

Comment: IMO, there is no separate electric or magnetic flux line. Both are constituted by stream of virtual photons. Therefore the electron from which the electromagnetic phenomenon originates, has a single unified electromagnetic flux field. Depending on the type of its interaction with other particles, its radiated flux is curled thus magnetic flux or not curled thus electric flux. Unified electromagnetic flux field manifold of the dressed electron: https://www.horntorus.com/particle-model/mm-index.html