# Why the magnetic field inside solenoid is parallel?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

We know that inside solenoid the magnetic field are same at all point's and are parallel to each other

My question is why they are parallel as my teacher explained it as solenoid is set of multiple circular loops and one face coil form North pole while other will form South pole and magnetic field lines from both poles will join in parallel

I think this explanation is not correct

Any response would be appreciated

Comment: By reflection symmetry about any plane perpendicular to its axis, the magnetic field is necessary parallel to the axis. See for example this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/780830/for-what-reasons-of-symmetry-does-the-magnetic-field-inside-an-infinite-solenoid/780850#780850)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the magnetic field pattern for a single loop.

[image]

See what happens as more loops are added but please not I do not have the facility to change the colours to reflect a larger field strength and to combine the field lines.
The diagram below is just copies of the first diagram displaced and superimposed on the first diagram.

[image]

However I think that it does illustrate the parallel nature of the field lines inside a series displaced coils (solenoid)?

Answer (score 0):

[![This picture is from the Internet][1]][1]

This isn't really my answer. It's just a picture from the Internet.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olb7b.png