# Can the signs of charge of electron and proton be reversed?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conventions

I was thinking that the electron, proton, neutron etc. are human given names to some particles. So, are the signs, positive of proton and negative of electron, given just to show their opposite behaviour? If yes, then can we assume electron to be positive and proton to be negative? And can the direction of electric fields (emerging from positive and converging to negative charge) be reversed if we assume that the sign is reversed? In short,what I want to ask whether the electric fields really emerge from a positive charge and move inwards to a negative charge or are they just assumed to do so to show opposite behaviour of the two charges(and if proton can be taken as negative)?

Also, I'm not talking about change in current but electric field due to reversed sign of charges.

Comment: Even electric fields are not some real physical thing. They were defined by humans(first by Faraday) just make it easier for us to visualise fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the charge naming convention wrong?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17109/)

Comment: Closer duplicate: [If electrons were positive and protons were negative, would life be different?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356257/)