# Benefits of the sign convention for electrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, electricity, subatomic

Benjamin Franklin considered electrons to be positive, but J.J. Thompson considered them negative. We obviously went with J.J. Thompson's convention.

Why? What were the benefits of moving to J.J. Thompson's convention when Benjamin Franklin had already established a convention?

Related: [Why is the charge naming convention wrong?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17109/why-is-the-charge-naming-convention-wrong)

Related: [Why are electrons defined to have negative charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75467/why-are-electrons-defined-to-have-negative-charge)

Comment: I don't think Benjamin Franklin knew about electrons