# Why aren't electrons positively charged?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, conventions

For the study of electric circuits, it seems like it would have made more sense to establish that electrons carry a positive charge, and protons a negative one. That way, arrows representing current would actually represent the flow of electrons. I've never come across a reason to support the convention in place today. So, besides the hassle of changing this universal agreement, is there a reason in favour of the one in place ?

Comment: It's the enormous hassle of changing it.  You can build a consistent system with the numeric value of the charges switched.  See [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/567/)

Comment: No, it's all historical convention. Say a big "thank you" to Ben Franklin, who guessed the direction of charge exchange incorrectly.  And, yes, it's too big a hassle to change now.  Consider the difficulty of switching the US and Britain to metric measurements.

Comment: The difficulty if switching from Imperial to Metric is (from experience) wildly over-exaggerated.  Changing sign conventions for charges would, by comparison, be a minefield given the amassed scientific and engineering documentation that would be rendered confusing as blazes for no practical gain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the charge naming convention wrong?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17109/). Oher duplicates include https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142150, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68471/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210984/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80503.