# IF electrons flow in opposite direction to the electric current then what constitutes the current?

Tags: electricity, electrons, electric-current

If electrons flow to the opposite direction to the electric current and the protons do not move instead they create the current, then what actually flows in the electric current? Since current is flow of anything in a particular direction then what flows along the direction of an electric current? Or is electric current a field which attracts the electrons towards it ?

Comment: Related: [Why is the charge naming convention wrong?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17109/why-is-the-charge-naming-convention-wrong)

Answer (score 2):

> what actually flows in the electric current

Electric charge.  From the Wikipedia article [Electric Current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current):

> An electric current is a flow of electric charge

Negative (by convention) electric charge is *carried* by electrons and so a flow of electrons is also a flow of electric charge.  But the negative sign of the charge means that the electric current (due to the flow of electrons) is in the opposite direction of the electron current.

If the charge on the electron had been deemed positive rather than negative, then the currents would be in the same direction.