# Direction of the current and the electrons

Tags: electricity, electrons, electric-current, charge, conventions

If the electric current is defined as Coulomb/second, why is the direction of the current is just the opposite of the direction of the flow of electrons?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17109/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It is entirely down to history and somebody deciding that the flow of "something" was from a positively (excess of "something") charged body to a negatively (deficit of "something") charged body.